# difference between MPMoviePlayerController and MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, http-live-streaming

Can anyone tell me about the differences between MPMoviePlayerController and MPMoviePlayerViewController?
Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

`MPMoviePlayerViewController` inherits from `UIViewController`,  and `MPMoviePlayerController` from `NSObject`.

From the Doc of `MPMoviePlayerController`:

> A movie player (of type MPMoviePlayerController) manages the playback
>   of a movie from a file or a network stream. Playback occurs in a view
>   owned by the movie player and takes place either fullscreen or inline.
>   You can incorporate a movie player’s view into a view hierarchy owned
>   by your app, or use an MPMoviePlayerViewController object to manage
>   the presentation for you.

From the Doc of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`:

> The MPMoviePlayerViewController class implements a simple view
>   controller for displaying full-screen movies. Unlike using an
>   MPMoviePlayerController object on its own to present a movie
>   immediately, you can incorporate a movie player view controller
>   wherever you would normally use a view controller. For example, you
>   can present it using a tab bar or navigation bar-based interface,
>   taking advantage of the transitions offered by those interfaces.